# How can i find Mongodb connection string for Prisma project?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prisma

I want to create a project using Prisma and i want to connect it to my local Mongodb database but i cant find the connection string it should be like this : http://user1:myPassword@localhost:27017/admin
If anyone knows how can i find my user and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You have to create the user in your mongodb server.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prisma CLI, you can configure your database connection in the file docker-compose.yml,

```
  version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4466:4466'
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: mongodb://http://user1:myPassword@localhost:27017/admin
            database: mydb
```

Check this [link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/releases-and-maintenance/features-in-preview/mongodb-b6o5/) for more info